# Can't resolve perl dependency: Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a tool written in perl to work but it seems no matter what I do I can't resolve the dependency for the DBI package.

`ERROR:  Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at line 15.`

I've tried:

- installing DBI using cpan, no errors on install but I still get the same error.
- Using the `make install` script in the DBI package manually.
- Copying DBI.pm to some of the directories in `@INC` manually.
- Trying to set `PERL5LIB` to each of the million places that perl installs the same package over and over again (As someone who's never used perl what possible reason is there for this?!?)
- Running perl -MCPAN -e'install

I don't know what else do to...

Comment: The best way to install modules in the system perl is with your package manager (e.g. yum, apt-get). What distro are you running?

Comment: Not on Linux, i'm on OSX

Comment: The first option "installing DBI using cpan" is the one to use. Can you show us the output that you get when you run that? All the directories listed in `@INC` seem to be system directories so you'd need to run the install as root.  You might want to look at using [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) to allow non-root installs to a directory of your choosing.

Comment: I tried installing it as root but it still gets the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a common recommendation on Linux is to not modify the system Perl and to use a different Perl installation for Perl code development.  Part of the rationale for that is that the OS relies on the system Perl and if the system Perl is modified/updated, it could break some functionality of the OS.

I'm not sure if that same concern also applies to OSX.  If it does, you may be able to use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) to help manage multiple Perl installations.  Since there is a note about a fix for [MacOSX 1.7 (Lion)](https://perlbrew.pl/FixLion.html), I'm assuming that perlbrew will work in MacOSx.

Using perlbrew might be a better way forward rather than continuing to modify the system Perl.